# Using Android Zebra tc70 with DataWedge barcode scanner but not getting end of line codes from scans

Tags: android, datawedge

This is an app that was working fine on an older device but since installing on a Zebra TC70 the barcode scans are not returned with end of line codes as they were before. I can't find a setting in DataWedge to add an eol code either. Do I need to program a solution for this, ie at the end of each scan I add an eol code to the text box string.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the huge amount of DataWedge settings there is a setting to append the scan result with a code, either an enter code or a tab code. This setting is in the profile. On the TC-70 its set to not append anything by default. Instructions [here on Zebra](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/DataWedge-for-Android-Send-Enter-or-Tab-after-scanning?language=en_US).